# Un/marshalling base64 encoded binary data as stream

Tags: java, xml, stream, jaxb, base64

I have an application importing and exporting data from an Oracle database to/from XML using JAXB. Now there are some BLOB fields in the DB containing uploaded files which I would like to have in the XML as a base64 encoded string. This works quite well out of the box with JAXB using   `@XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")` as done below:

```
@XmlType
public class DocumentTemplateFile {

    // other fields ommited

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")
    private byte[] data;

    // other code ommited
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the whole file content is stored in memory because of the byte array. Depending on the size of the file this could cause some issues.

I was therefore wondering if there's a way to create an `XmlAdapter` or similar that gets Streams from and to the file, so that I can stream it directly to / from the DB's BLOB without having the whole content in memory. I was thinking on something similar to this:

```
public class BlobXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<InputStream, OutputStream> {

  @Override
  public InputStream marshal(final OutputStream value) throws Exception {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public OutputStream unmarshal(final InputStream value) throws Exception {
    return null;
  }

}
```

This is obviously only an illustrative example so that you can have an idea of what I'm looking for. The end solution doesn't necessarily have to make use of `XmlAdater`s. All I need is a way to hook on the un/marshalling process and stream the data through a buffer / queue rather than storing everything in a byte array.

Answer (score 2):

this solution uses following third party library. you should use following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jlibs-xsd</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
    <id>jlibs-snapshots-repository</id>
    <name>JLibs Snapshots Repository</name>
    <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/santhosh-tekuri/maven-repository/master</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

We need to use following custom `XmlAdapter`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * @author Santhosh Kumar Tekuri
 */
public class Base64Adapter extends XmlAdapter<String, File>{
    @Override
    public File unmarshal(String v) throws Exception{
        return new File(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(File v) throws Exception{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

now change your pojo to use above adapter:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.io.File;

@XmlRootElement
public class DocumentTemplateFile {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String userName;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "base64Binary")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Base64Adapter.class)
    public File data;
}
```

now the following helper class should be used to read xml file:

```
import jlibs.xml.Namespaces;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.DOMLSInputList;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSParser;
import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSUtil;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSElementDeclaration;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSSimpleTypeDefinition;
import org.apache.xerces.xs.XSTypeDefinition;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Santhosh Kumar Tekuri
 */
public class JAXBBlobUtil{
    public static XSModel generateSchemas(Class clazz) throws Exception{
        final Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> schemas = new HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
        JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz).generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                schemas.put(suggestedFileName, bout);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bout);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }
        });

        DOMLSInputList lsInputList = new DOMLSInputList();
        for(Map.Entry<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> entry : schemas.entrySet()){
            ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(entry.getValue().toByteArray());
            lsInputList.addStream(bin, entry.getKey(), null);
        }
        return new XSParser().parse(lsInputList);
    }

    private static Object unmarshal(Class clazz, InputSource is) throws Exception{
        XSModel xsModel = generateSchemas(clazz);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XMLReader xmlReader = factory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        xmlReader = new Base64Filter(xmlReader, xsModel);
        return context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new SAXSource(xmlReader, is));
    }

    private static class Base64Filter extends XMLFilterImpl{
        private XSModel schema;
        private List<QName> xpath = new ArrayList();
        private FileWriter fileWriter;
        public Base64Filter(XMLReader parent, XSModel schema){
            super(parent);
            this.schema = schema;
        }

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException{
            xpath.clear();
            super.startDocument();
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException{
            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);

            xpath.add(new QName(uri, localName));
            XSElementDeclaration elem = XSUtil.findElementDeclaration(schema, this.xpath);
            if(elem!=null){
                XSTypeDefinition type = elem.getTypeDefinition();
                if(type.getTypeCategory()==XSTypeDefinition.SIMPLE_TYPE){
                    XSSimpleTypeDefinition simpleType = (XSSimpleTypeDefinition)type;
                    while(!Namespaces.URI_XSD.equals(simpleType.getNamespace()))
                        simpleType = (XSSimpleTypeDefinition)simpleType.getBaseType();
                    if("base64Binary".equals(simpleType.getName())){
                        try{
                            File file = File.createTempFile("data", "binary");
                            file.deleteOnExit();
                            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            super.characters(absolutePath.toCharArray(), 0, absolutePath.length());
                        }catch(IOException ex){
                            throw new SAXException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException{
            try{
                if(fileWriter==null)
                    super.characters(ch, start, length);
                else
                    fileWriter.write(ch, start, length);
            }catch(IOException ex){
                throw new SAXException(ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException{
            xpath.remove(xpath.size() - 1);
            try{
                if(fileWriter!=null)
                    fileWriter.close();
                fileWriter = null;
            }catch(IOException ex){
                throw new SAXException(ex);
            }
            super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        }
    };
}
```

Now read xml file as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DocumentTemplateFile obj = (DocumentTemplateFile)unmarshal(DocumentTemplateFile.class, new InputSource("sample.xml"));
    // obj.data refers to File which contains base64 encoded data
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood this code. I guess, it's supposed to write the base64 parsed content to a file during unmarshalling, so that I can store the file content to the DB after the parsing process, right?

Anyway, I think it's going in the right direction with the XMLFilter. Is there something similar for the **marshalling** process, i. e. a filter getting events when the XML is marshalled?

Comment: the xmlfilter in above code writes base64 content to file. you can change it to decode and write to file as an exercise. yes. for mashalling you have to bring entire file into memory, so i left marshalling.

Answer (score 1):

create custom `XmlAdapter` as below:

```
public class Base64FileAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, File>{
    @Override
    public String marshal(File file) throws Exception {
        // todo: read file and convert to base64 and return
    }

    @Override
    public File unmarshal(String data) throws Exception {
        File file = File.createTempFile("dataFile", "binary");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        //todo: base64 decode string data and write bytes to file
        return file;
    }
}
```

now inside you bean, use it:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Base64FileAdapter.class)
private File dataFile;
```

now the entire binary content is stored in file. you can read/write from this file. and this file is deleted on jvm exit.

Comment: But this doesn't really prevent the whole file being in memory, right? Although, we are temporarily storing the file on the disk, it's still completely loaded into memory as a base64 encoded string as soon as JAXB does the marshalling process. So, from the memory consumption perspective I don't see any difference comparing to the solution using a byte array.

Comment: I you are loading 100's of such beans from JAXB, only the currently parsed binary data is in inmemory in constrast to having binary data of 100's of beans

Comment: Yes, that's clear. However, what if I have let's say a 10MB file in the DB's blob for **one** bean instance. This 10MB data would be in memory because of the `String`. That's why this is not really different from the `byte[]` approach, regarding memory consumption. Since the memory consumption is pretty much the same, I would prefer the array solution as it performs better, as I'm not writing anything to the disk.

Comment: in such case i would suggest use SAX or STAX

Comment: Can you post an example? I guess the problem with SAX or STAX would be that I would lose the advantages of JAXB isn't it? This issue will happen quite often as I have many such BLOB fields in the DB, however it's still pretty isolated, so that I'm not really willing to re-code everything using a different technology just to be able to stream the binary data in some edges of the project. The ideal would be if I could hook SAX or STAX without changing the processing of JAXB. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use JAXB with SAX. You will write a sax filter which finds when a base64 element read, it writes its content in streaming mode to a temp file, and gives jaxb the temp file path in base64 encoded format.